# Azure Scheduled WebJob - save diagnostics to Table store?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-diagnostics

I can successfully save my logs to Table store for a **continuous** WebJob, following these instructions: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/

However, if I make the WebJob **scheduled** (runs once every 5 mins), the logs do not show up in Table store. Is this a known limitation (and if so, why?), or does anyone know a way to make it work?

Note: I **can** see the logs in the Azure Portal, so I know the job runs correctly -- I just want to save these to a WADLogsTable.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793383/azure-web-job-the-job-is-missing-basic-auth-fields). Compress in a .zip the Release folder of your web job and then go to your azure webpage, click web jobs and add. Set your schedule in the menu that shows when you press add, you can change it later in your azure web job schedule menu.

Comment: Actually that is how I deployed it (zip file, upload via Azure Portal). Thanks though...