# azure web job "The job is missing basic auth fields"

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I made a web job for my azure website. It works when I click "Run Once" in the azure website web jobs tab but it doesn't work when I set it at determinate time every day.

The web job is marked as success but the it does nothing. I was checking the web jobs logs and it seems that there were five attempts but all of them shows: **Http Action - Request to host '******.scm.azurewebsites.net' failed: The job is missing basic auth fields**. I have the AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage in the website config, the web job config and in the azure connection string config, I added them everywhere hoping for a fix but it didn’t work.

It was working fine yesterday but today I made a small change, when I uploaded the new version it didn’t work at the time it was set. The change was a new column in a sql query. Has anyone gotten this error? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: did you found a solution?

Comment: Load the web job using the azure webpage and set the execution time there.

Comment: But what if im deployng using git integration?

Answer (score 2):

Loading the web job using the azure web page and then configuring the schedule solved the problem. I don´t know why my deploy from visual studio is not working with schedule when it worked fine 2 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly are you finding that "missing basic auth fields" error message? What type of scheduled job are you using? I suspect Azure Scheduler. Are you finding this error in the Azure Scheduler logs?

If you're in the Basic or Standard pricing tier, since you're using the WebJobs SDK, there is a simpler schedule mechanism that you can use. See TimerTrigger [here](http://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Hello Mathew, you are correct I am using Azure Scheduler and I saw the error there. I have a basic pricing tier web and used Visual Studio to publish the web job but now I added a new one using the azure webpage add new web job option, I hope it works with at the set time. If that doesn’t work, I will add the json mentioned in [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduledCRON) webpage. I will check the one you mentioned too, thank you for the help.